# Objective-c NSDateFormatter timezone reverts to GMT

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am playing about with some timezone calculations and I have noticed quite an annoying error which is causing me problems.

If I create a date, use NSDateformatter to convert it to a certain time zone, retrieve that string, and then use dateformatter to convert the string back into a date object, it keeps reverting to my local GMT time.

Example

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"COT"]];

NSString *str = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"%@", str);
//prints 2015-02-04 10:33:45 GMT-5

NSDate *newDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:str];
NSLog(@"%@", newDate);
//Prints 2015-02-04 15:33:45 +0000
```

Why does it keep reverting back to GMT? I need that date object to accurately reflect the time zone I have set the dateformatter to for some testing purposes, so this is quite a frustrating issue.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: An `NSDate` object does not have a timezone. When you convert it to text you should use an `NSDateFormatter` with a specified timezone.

Comment: I have specified the timezone in the dateformatter. Read my code

Comment: Sorry. I thought you were asking about `NSLog(@"%@", newDate);`.

Comment: The suffix of the NSDate contains the GMT offset, when I use dateformatter and set it to a new time zone, I need that suffix to accurately reflect the time zone I have set it to

Comment: @AdamM: No, you mean "the result of converting the NSDate to a String contains the GMT offset". That's not the same thing as the NSDate itself having that information.

Comment: Ah my mistake, I thought the +0000 at the end of NSDate contained the offset, so if I had set it to a difference time zone, it would reflect that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the problem is that `NSDate` itself (i.e. the value you're logging at the end) doesn't have a time zone - it's just a moment in time. You're specifying the time zone *when formatting the value using `stringFromDate*, and you're still using that when you *parse* the value back to an`NSDate`... but the`NSDate` value itself doesn't remember the time zone.

To give a different example, imagine you had an `IntegerFormatter` for `NSInteger`, which let you say whether you wanted to format and parse in hex or decimal. You could format the decimal value 16 to 0x10, and then parse that value back... but the `NSInteger` wouldn't "remember" that it was parsed from hex. It's exactly the same here - the time zone plays a part in the parsing (at least when the value itself doesn't specify the time zone) but it isn't part of the result in itself.

> I need that date object to accurately reflect the time zone

Then you need to keep the time zone separately alongside the `NSDate`, basically... (Looking at the documentation, it sounds like `NSCalendarDate` did what you want, but that's deprecated.)

Comment: Ah that is unfortunate. shame they deprecated NSCalenderdate, that would have been perfect for my purposes. Will have to rework my code then. Marking as correct. Thanks for the information!